# Change letter and word spacing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to change the text style in a textarea:

HTML

```
    <!--text area-->

      <textarea placeholder="paste text here" size = "12" id="text" rows="5" cols="90" ></textarea>

      <!--text alter inputs-->

      <br/><br/>
letter spacing: <input type="number" placeholder="#" id="letterSpace"/>

<br/><br/>
word spacing: <input type="number" placeholder="#" id="wordSpace"/>

      <br/><br/>
line spacing: <input type="number" placeholder="#" id="lineSpace"/>

    <!--apply changes button-->

      <br/><br/><button id="go">update text!</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT (jQuery)

```
$("#go").click(function(){

   //SET VARS

  var letterSpace = $("#letterSpace").val();

  var wordSpace = $("#wordSpace").val();

  var lineSpace = $("#lineSpace").val();

  //UPDATE TEXT

   $("#text").css("letter-spacing", letterSpace);
   $("#text").css("word-spacing", wordSpace);
   $("#text").css("line-height", lineSpace);

});
```

and it works for the line-height but not for the letter or word spacing. Does anyone know why might this be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are your units? Are you using em? px? %?

Comment: You have to specify some kind of units. `px`, `pt`, `em`, `rem`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code ,you just need to define the units in your JQuery code.I tried the code given by you it works for me after changing this way.

```
 $("#go").click(function(){

   //SET VARS

  var letterSpace = $("#letterSpace").val();

  var wordSpace = $("#wordSpace").val();

  var lineSpace = $("#lineSpace").val();

  //UPDATE TEXT

   $("#text").css("letter-spacing", letterSpace+"px");
   $("#text").css("word-spacing", wordSpace+"px");
   $("#text").css("line-height", lineSpace+"px");

});
```

By appending `px` with the numbers it worked perfectly for me.

Please let me know if this is helpful for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jQuery css expects an object. you may need to enter something like this in your input:

```
{ "font-weight": "bold" }
```

and then use `$(el).css(JSON.parse(wordSpace))`

Answer (score 0):

You must define valid values for letterspacing: normal, length, initial, inherit, etc. and for numeric values suffix or append "px" in or to the input value